# Same thread running the same recursive code seems to consume more stack memory in Java 8 compared to Java 7

Tags: memory, recursion, java-8, stack-overflow, jvm-hotspot

I am asking a question about "java stack overflow" in the "stackoverflow" site :)

A particular thread which makes some recursive function calls for a particular input runs fine in **Oracle Java 7 (64 bit)** for a configured stack size of 228k (-Xss228k).

However, the same thread running the same recursive code for the same input throws a **java.lang.StackOverflowError** in **Oracle Java 8 (64 bit)** for the same stack size of 228k. It runs fine in Java 8 if the stack size is increased to 512k (-Xss512k).

Any idea why this could happen? Have any changes been made in Java 8 (Hotspot JVM) compared to Java 7 which could increase the stack memory consumption for recursive function calls? I can provide additional details if required.

(Edit) **NOTE**: The same recursion depth works "always" in Java 7 but fails "always" in Java 8 for a stack size of 228k.

Comment: Stack consumption is not exactly predictable. Without code examples, it’s impossible to tell whether one out of the dozens of possible reasons applies to your particular issue. See for example [“Why is the max recursion depth I can reach non-deterministic?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27043922/2711488)

Comment: @Holger The same recursion depth works "always" in Java 7 but fails "always" in Java 8 for a stack size of 228k. So, do the non-deterministic factors still apply in my scenario? Meanwhile, I will try to come up with a code example soon.

Comment: Are your JVMs both 64bit? Both 32bit? One is 32, other is 64?

Comment: @TagirValeev Both JVMs are 64 bit.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote [a small test](https://gist.github.com/amaembo/2687d2b1dbd8ae6b3df4) for different recursion scenarios (static or instance method, different number of int parameters). Here's the results (number of calls before `StackOverflowError` occurs) on different versions of HotSpot JVM 64bit with `-Xss228k` option. Note that numbers differ somewhat between runs (I launched twice with every JVM):

```
          St/0  St/1  St/2  St/3  St/4  In/0  In/1  In/2  In/3  In/4
1.7.0_60  2720  2519  2309  2131  1979  2519  2309  2131  1979  1847
1.7.0_60  2716  2516  2306  2128  1976  2516  2306  2128  1976  1845
1.7.0_79  2716  2516  2306  2128  1976  2516  2306  2128  1976  1845
1.7.0_79  2729  2528  2317  2139  1986  2528  2317  2139  1986  1853
1.7.0_80  2718  2518  2308  2130  1978  2518  2308  2130  1978  1846
1.7.0_80  2738  2536  2324  2146  1992  2536  2324  2146  1992  1859
____________________________________________________________________
1.8.0_25  2818  2469  2263  2089  1940  2469  2263  2089  1940  1810
1.8.0_25  3279  2468  2262  2088  1939  2468  2262  2088  1939  1810
1.8.0_40  2714  2467  2262  2088  1938  2467  2262  2088  1938  1809
1.8.0_40  2735  2486  2279  2104  1953  2486  2279  2104  1953  1823
1.8.0_60  2729  2481  2274  2099  1949  2481  2274  2099  1949  1819
1.8.0_60  2719  2472  2266  2091  1942  2472  2266  2091  1942  1812
____________________________________________________________________
1.9_b80   2717  2470  2264  2090  1941  2470  2264  2090  1941  1811
1.9_b80   2715  2468  2263  2088  1939  2468  2263  2088  1939  1810
```

It's quite expected that `Instance/0` is the same as `Static/1` and so on as instance call need to pass `this` as an additional argument.

So indeed there's some degradation of number of recursive calls allowed (except for `Static/0` case) betwee JDK 7 and JDK 8: you lose around 30-40 calls (roughly 5%) of total count. So probably in your application you was very close to the limit. By the way I noticed a sudden jump between `-Xss256k` and `-Xss260k` (tested on 1.8.0_40):

```
          St/0  St/1  St/2  St/3  St/4  In/0  In/1  In/2  In/3  In/4
-Xss256k  2724  2476  2270  2095  1945  2476  2270  2095  1945  1816
-Xss260k  4493  3228  2959  2731  2536  3228  2959  2731  2536  2367
```

So you may try to increase stack size to `-Xss260k` and it should be enough for your task.

By the way 32-bit JVM allows much more calls with the same `-Xss228k`:

```
          St/0  St/1  St/2  St/3  St/4  In/0  In/1  In/2  In/3  In/4
7u67_32b  7088  5078  4655  4297  3990  5078  4655  4297  3990  3724
7u67_32b  6837  5092  4667  4308  4001  5092  4667  4308  4001  3734
```

Thus it's also possible that you've switched from 32-bit Java-7 to 64-bit Java-8. In this case, of course much more stack space is needed as even with compressed OOPs pointers in the stack seem to be 64bit, thus occupying more space.

Comment: So your test didn’t give the JIT a chance to kick in? As shown in the linked question, it can change the results by factor six…

Comment: @Holger, for some reason St/0 is the less stable case (see 1.8.0_25/St_0) and it was tested in linked question. For the JIT-compiled code the recursion level can be much higher (up to 13000 calls in the first test). The question is whether the compiler has enough time to JIT-compile. Usually the program is dead on the first StackOverflow error, thus I omitted the analysis of the further launches. In general my results are consistent with yours. Probably in St/0 JIT-compiler has some chance. And of course the results might differ with more complex method body (backedges, etc.)

Comment: @TagirValeev Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! In my case, both JVMs are 64 bit. As you mentioned, this seems to be the case in my scenario:

"So indeed there's some degradation of number of recursive calls allowed (except for Static/0 case) betwee JDK 7 and JDK 8: you lose around 30-40 calls (roughly 5%) of total count. So probably in your application you was very close to the limit. By the way I noticed a sudden jump between -Xss256k and -Xss260k. So you may try to increase stack size to -Xss260k and it should be enough for your task."

Comment: @TagirValeev I was also going to try and come up with a stack size between 228K and 512k which would suffice for my thread. I will most likely end up setting the stack size to 260k as you have suggested :)

By the way, do you have any idea as to why we are observing the 5% degradation (roughly) in the number of recursive calls allowed between Java 7 and Java 8? Any Java 8 documentation which talks about changes which can lead to such a degradation?

Comment: @SanjayBhat, no I don't know. I guess it's not specified.

Comment: @TagirValeev FYI for my scenario, I found that the thread which worked fine for a stack size of 228k in Java 7 needed a stack size of 328k in Java 8 i.e., 100k more than Java 7.

Comment: JDK 7 has 2 yellow pages on thread stack, but JDK 8 has 3 yellow pages on Windows, hence the difference. Extra stack page (4K) provides right about 50 more interpreted calls. [Here is](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-runtime-dev/2013-June/007679.html) the relevant discussion on *hotspot-runtime-dev* list, and [here is](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/rev/cd54c7e92908) the corresponding fix in JDK 8.

Comment: Another related difference between JDK 7 vs. JDK 8 is JIT compilation policy. E.g. JDK 8 has TieredCompilation on by default. This means Java methods are first compiled with C1, which is more greedy in stack usage comparing to C2. See the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517934/why-does-the-count-of-calls-of-a-recursive-method-causing-a-stackoverflowerror-v).