# How to get the dynamic call graph of a java program

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I can't get or modify the source code of the program. So I'm trying to read the jvm(hotspot) source code to see if I can do something when it fetch the "call method" instruction, but it seems very complex.

I want to know where is the relevant code I should start with or if there is other way to do this.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking for. You can use a **profiler**, such as YourKit or JProfiler to *profile* the execution of a Java program. But that just records what is going on. The idea to *patch* a JVM in order to do something special ... honestly: that sounds crazy. I am a 20 year Java programmer, and I wouldn't dare to do that. That is no a viable, robust option to change the behavior of an existing appliction, imho.

Comment: Beyond that: asking for pointers to libraries, tools, source code ... that is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to modify JVM code to intercept method invocation. There is a standard documented way to do this using [JVMTI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html).

You'll need to create an agent that will set callbacks for [MethodEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#MethodEntry) / [MethodExit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#MethodExit) JVMTI events, compile it to a shared library, then run Java with `-agentpath:/path/to/libYourAgent.so` option.

See an example of using MethodEntry / MethodExit events in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185905/is-there-a-way-to-know-maximally-reached-jvm-call-stack-depth-for-a-particular-p).