# OpenJDK Tracking ReentrantLock lock and unlock

Tags: java, jvm, interpreter, instrumentation, jvm-hotspot

I am doing runtime instrumentation using the interpreter.
My focus now is adding a function call before any `ReEntractLock` `lock()` and `unlock()` function.

For reference, this is the Test.java:

```java
class Test {
    static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public String name;

    public Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void test() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name);
            name = "World";
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

by examining the bytecode, I found that on each lock/unlock, there is an `invokeinterafce` bytecode.

```
public void test();
   Code:
       0: getstatic     #13                 // Field lock:Ljava/util/concurrent/locks/Lock;
       3: invokeinterface #17,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.lock:()V
       8: ...
      26: getstatic     #13                 // Field lock:Ljava/util/concurrent/locks/Lock;
      29: invokeinterface #23,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.unlock:()V
      34: ...
```

So I went into `src/hotspot/cpu/x86/templateTable_x86.cpp`, and added a vm leaf call.

```cpp
void TemplateTable::invokeinterface(int byte_no) {
...
// rbx: Method* to call
  // rcx: receiver
  // Check for abstract method error
  // Note: This should be done more efficiently via a throw_abstract_method_error
  //       interpreter entry point and a conditional jump to it in case of a null
  //       method.
  __ testptr(rbx, rbx);
  __ jcc(Assembler::zero, no_such_method);

  __ profile_arguments_type(rdx, rbx, rbcp, true);

  __ call_VM_leaf(CAST_FROM_FN_PTR(address, SharedRuntime::monitor_invoke), rbx); // <- the call, rbx contains the method pointer
  ...
}
```

However, this way I get every method called by invoke interface, and the only way **I** could think was to check the name, like this

`if (strstr(name, "java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock"))...`

This however, looks bad and will probably add too much additional overhead.

Is there another way I can track `lock/unlock` calls made by `java.util.concurrent` or a cheaper way to do the name comparison?

Comment: You instrument the _interpreter_, which is slow in the first place. So why care about interpreter performance? If you need _fast_ tracing, go for bytecode instrumentation instead - this will cover JIT-compiled code, too.

Comment: @apangin Your point is correct. You mean inside c1/c2 or in the interpreter/bytecode? I suppose I could try that too, thanks for the hint. Currently I am running with `-Xint` to avoid JIT optimizing stuff away.

Comment: What exactly are you tracing it for/what information do you need? You might be able to inject yourself in the `ReentrentLock` implementation  (which is Java code) or use existing profilers/tools or agents.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying I try to track when a thread performs a lock/unlock operation, I have already done it for `synchronized` blocks. The goal is to make something similar to tsan, built in the jvm.

Answer (score 2):

Instrumenting `invokeinterface` is not enough. If `lock` field is declared with `ReentrantLock` type, then `lock.lock()` will be called using `invokevirtual` rather than `invokeinterface`.

The good news is that you don't need to change VM sources to trace method invocation. There is a standard API for such things called [JVM Tool Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jvmti.html) (JVM TI). All you need is to create an agent that installs a callback for [MethodEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jvmti.html#MethodEntry) and [MethodExit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jvmti.html#MethodExit) events. You many find an example of using these events in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52194541/3448419).

As mentioned in the documentation, enabling MethodEntry/MethodExit events may significantly degrade performance. To intercept calls to `ReentrantLock.lock`/`unlock` methods in a more performant way, consider using [Bytecode instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jvmti.html#bci). The idea is to change the implementation of `lock`/`unlock` methods dynamically at runtime, inserting the bytecode to call your monitoring function. Such instrumented methods can benefit from JIT compilation and all JVM optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing, was editing the `ReentrantLock.java` file.

I added a native function in `Runtime.java` which then called the VM and handled the `lock/unlock` operation.

Inside `src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Runtime.c`, I added the following function:

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Runtime_handleLock(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
{
    JVM_handleLock(env);
}
```

Then inside `src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Runtime.java`:

```java
public native void handleLock();
```

Finally, inside `src/hotspot/share/prims/jvm.cpp`:

```cpp
JVM_ENTRY(void, JVM_handleLock(JNIEnv* env))
    if (thread && thread->is_Java_thread()) {
      JavaThread *jt = (JavaThread *) thread;
      frame fr = jt->last_frame();
      // To get the actual sender frame, we need to skip Runtime and java.util.concurrent frames
      RegisterMap map(jt,
                  RegisterMap::UpdateMap::skip,
                  RegisterMap::ProcessFrames::skip,
                  RegisterMap::WalkContinuation::skip);
      fr = fr.sender(&map); // is there a better way?
      fr = fr.sender(&map);

      if (fr.is_interpreted_frame()) {
        Method *m      = fr.interpreter_frame_method();
        address bcp    = fr.interpreter_frame_bcp();

        ...
      }
    }
JVM_END
```

I added the functions inside, `make/data/hotspot-symbols/symbols-unix`:

```
JVM_handleLock
```

Then to actually handle the `lock/unlock` functions, I only needed to add a `Runtime` call inside the corresponding function.

E.g for `src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java`:

```cpp
    public void lock() {
        sync.lock();
        Runtime.getRuntime().handleLock();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you making a simple matter complicated, modifying JDK source code in multiple languages instead of simply following the advice given and use regular Java instrumentation? AspectJ, Byte Buddy, ASM etc are your friends.