# how to find default stack size in java

Tags: memory-management, jvm, performance-testing, jvm-arguments, stack-size

i have to find the default stack size of  Zulu SA-linux64 and unable to find any info regarding this . We are not using -xss but i want to know the default stack size of this jvm . How can we check

want to know command to check the default stack size

Comment: Note that you can typically adjust the stack size on a per-thread basis too but it's platform dependent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829317/how-to-extend-stack-size-without-access-to-jvm-settings

Answer (score 0):

In OpenJDK, the default Java stack size on Linux-amd64 is 1024 KB.
You may check this with the following command:

```
$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                  = 1024        {pd product} {default}
     intx ThreadStackSize                          = 1024        {pd product} {default}
     intx VMThreadStackSize                        = 1024        {pd product} {default}
openjdk version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu21.30+15-CA (build 21.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu21.30+15-CA (build 21.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: great its worked thank you so much for the help

Comment: @AnkitaSharma Please mark the answer as accepted then