# return just before stack is about to overflow

Tags: java

Is there any way I can return from a recursive function just before it is about to overflow?

```
public static void func() {
   // if it is about to overflow
   // return 
   func();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    func();
}
```

I have tried `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` but it returns a same `int` every time.
I have also tried to calculate `freeMemory` by subtracting `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` but that is not working.

Is there any way in Java to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: Recommended read: [Why is the max recursion depth I can reach non-deterministic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27043922/2711488)