# How to get the full stacktrace of a StackOverflowError without restarting the application

Tags: java, jvm, runtime, stack-overflow, stack-trace

I currently hava a running Java application, which has a bug. I don't know how to fully reproduce it and it didn't happen for weeks until now. When it occurs one times, I can reproduce it over and over again easily until I restart the application. The bug causes a StackOverflowError because of a recursion and I don't know how this happens. The printed stacktrace of the `StackOverflowError` isn't helpful because it contains only the repeating part, but not the more insteresting initial part, because the JVM has a limit for stacktrace entries. The `-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=...` can be used to set this limit as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165753/how-to-get-full-stack-of-stackoverflowerror). The problem is that I think I have to restart my application in order to add this flag. But if I do so, I won't be able to reproduce the bug anymore. Is there any solution how I can get the full stacktrace or set this flag without restarting the application?

Comment: You can attach a debugger to the running application to inspect the entire stack.

Comment: What's wrong with the question? Why do people downvote this?

Comment: I don't know, as I didn't downvote (but I think your comment got routed back to me as a ping because nobody else commented). I think it's a reasonable question, and I gave a suggestion, but I don't have the time to write a full answer to high quality at the moment.

Comment: Sorry my comment was not targeting you but it was rather a general question what I can improve. I will try to attach a debugger, thanks.

Comment: It seems like this is not possible. According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html a VM that is to be debugged with jdb must be started with the options `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_shmem,server=y,suspend=n`

Comment: Ack - this is part of the reason why I was remiss to write a full answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know at least two solutions.

1. Create [HotSpot Serviceability Agent](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/creating-your-own-debugging-tools#anchor_5) tool to find the address of `MaxJavaStackTraceDepth` variable in memory, and then update the memory of the process using OS-specific mechanism.
2. Attach a [JVM TI agent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html) that intercepts `StackOverflowErrors` and prints a stack trace right from the agent.

Here is the code for the first solution (as it is presumably shorter):

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.Address;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class ChangeVMFlag extends Tool {
    private static String pid;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Address addr = VM.getVM().getCommandLineFlag("MaxJavaStackTraceDepth").getAddress();
        long addrValue = VM.getVM().getDebugger().getAddressValue(addr);

        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/" + pid + "/mem", "rw")) {
            raf.seek(addrValue);
            raf.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(1_000_000));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pid = args[0];
        new ChangeVMFlag().execute(new String[]{pid});
    }
}
```

This tool changes the value of `MaxJavaStackTraceDepth` in the target process to 1 million.
Note: it uses Linux-specific `/proc` API to write into the target process' memory. Other OSes have different interfaces.

**How to run**

On JDK 8

```
java -cp .:$JAVA_HOME/lib/sa-jdi.jar ChangeVMFlag <pid>
```

On JDK 9+

```
java --add-modules=jdk.hotspot.agent \
     --add-exports jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.tools=ALL-UNNAMED \
     --add-exports jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED \
     --add-exports jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger=ALL-UNNAMED \
     ChangeVMFlag <pid>
```