# Is it possible to disable `-XX:+PrintCompilation` and `-verbose:gc"` at runtime?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, performance-testing, jvm-hotspot

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513259/391161), I am using the following flags when running performance tests.

```
  -XX:+PrintCompilation
  -verbose:gc
```

This was very useful for debugging what JVM activities were happening during the timing phase, but the output is less useful when I am merely computing statistics and printing output about the benchmark that just ran.

Is there a way to disable one or both of these flags at runtime so that I can turn them off after the timing phase?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Which OS and JDK version are you interested in?

Comment: @apangin I'm running on Linux and OSX, JDK 11.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easy to turn off GC logs in runtime, since GC logs are included in [Unified JVM Logging](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158) framework.

**From the command line**

```
jcmd <pid> VM.log what=gc=off
```

**From within the application**

```
ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().invoke(
        new ObjectName("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand"),
        "vmLog",
        new Object[]{new String[]{"what=gc=off"}},
        new String[]{"[Ljava.lang.String;"}
);
```

---

Unfortunately, `-XX:+PrintCompilation` is not a manageable flag and does not obey Unified JVM Logging. However, it's possible to change it, too.

I already showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65244713/3448419) how to modify a JVM flag externally using the Serviceability Agent. Here is one more way to do this.

The idea is to find the memory address of the flag and modify the value right in the memory. Below is an example how to achieve this on Linux.

1. Find the base address of the loaded JVM library:

```
$ grep libjvm.so /proc/<pid>/maps
7f57435ca000-7f574470d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2342674    /usr/java/jdk-11/lib/server/libjvm.so
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

2. Find the offset of `PrintCompilation` symbol in `libjvm.so`:

```
$ nm /usr/java/jdk-11/lib/server/libjvm.so | grep PrintCompilation
000000000144d7ff b PrintCompilation
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

3. Now write `0` into the process memory at the address `base + offset`:

```
$ printf '\x00' | dd of=/proc/<pid>/mem bs=1 count=1 seek=$((0x7f57435ca000 + 0x144d7ff)) conv=notrunc
```

That's it. `PrintCompilation` flag has been turned off.

**Bonus**

The same trick can be done directly from a Java application: read `/proc/pid/maps` like a regular file, parse ELF format of `libjvm.so` to find the symbol offset, and finally use `Unsafe` to write a byte at the given address. [Here is the complete example](https://github.com/odnoklassniki/one-elf/blob/master/test/one/jvm/HotspotFlags.java).

**Update**

I've added a [macOS example](https://gist.github.com/apangin/498c7a3fde345341b432cc079212166c) of modifying JVM flags in runtime from within a Java application. The usage is as simple as

```
VMFlags.setBooleanFlag("PrintCompilation", true);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there an equivalent trick for OSX?

Comment: I wonder, when `-XX:+PrintCompilation` is not manageable directly, what is the reason for that? And couldn't it be unsafe to change it the way shown here?

Comment: @merlin2011 Yes. Do you want to change the flag externally or from Java code?

Comment: @akuzminykh For historical reasons. I believe the flag *can* be manageable at runtime, just nobody cared before. It's safe to change the flag this way, as it is queried just a like regular bool variable, and there are no implicit dependencies on this flag other than for logging.