# Fetching JIT compilation failures

Tags: java, jvm, jit

Is there a way to fetch the JIT compilation failures in a running jvm?

In that running jvm, using jstat it is possible to fetch the last failed compilations. But I want to see all the failed compilations since restart. 20+ failures since the restart.

I can enable PrintCompilation, but for that I've to restart the server. In my case, it is needed to check the failures without restarting the servers.

Analysis reason:
There is a sudden spike in memory used. Approx 2GB. Suspecting some heavy compilation done by JIT. Based on my past experiences, such heavy compilations have failed with COMPILER OUT OF NODES reason.

Randomness is there in this memory issue occurrence. If I restart the server it may not happen again.

Comment: I would be shocked if this were possible.

Comment: See [Is it possible to disable `-XX:+PrintCompilation` and `-verbose:gc"` at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65909269/2711488). You can also get extensive diagnostics, see https://ideone.com/EZD5Jn I don’t know whether this will help you, as I don’t know how to reproduce the JIT compilation failures you described.